# Insert a PHP variable in a MySql SQL Statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to do like this using PHP and MySql PDO:

```
//PHP Variables
$msg_a = 'Too Little';
$msg_b = 'Score OK';

$sql = "select if(stdScore >= stdRequired, $msg_a, $msg_b) from scores;"

$results = $conn->prepare($Sql);

$results->execute();
```

AFAIK this should have worked. But I keep getting the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

How can something like this be done?

Comment: **PHP variables are case-sensitive.**

Comment: Your code is _still_ open to SQL injection. PDO is not a magic bullet, and you need to use it correctly with bound parameters instead of string concatenation

Comment: Why bother to use `prepare` if you still interpolate query strings?

Comment: echo $sql; and run it in server to check if query is correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
$results = $conn->prepare($Sql);
```

---------------------------------------------^ (capital S)

it should be with a lowercase `s`

```
$results = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

because you have:

```
$sql = "select if(stdScore >= stdRequired, $msg_a, $msg_b) 
        from scores";(//semicolon after double quotes)
```

---^
with a lowercase `s` (`$sql`)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

```
$sql = "select if(stdScore >= stdRequired, $msg_a, $msg_b) from scores";

$results = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: Isn't necesary.  Php allows you to insert variables directly into strings.

Comment: @MrVimes, What is not neccessary. ?

Comment: using those quote characters. PHP allows direct insertion like this - "Hello world $myvar Hello hello".  The questioner's problem is not the string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way ?

```
$sql = "select if(stdScore >= stdRequired, "'.$msg_a.'", "'.$msg_b.'") from scores;"
```

Comment: we usually try the above way as you mentioned when our php variables are not getting interpreted inside the query but i dont think the OP is getting the mentioned error due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using PDO **don't do query string interpolation** leaving your code vulnerable to sql injections and value escaping problems. Instead use prepared statements properly.

Your code could've looked something like

```php
$msg_a = 'Too Little';
$msg_b = 'Score OK';
// use placeholders in a query string
$sql = "SELECT IF(stdScore >= stdRequired, :msg_a, :msg_b) msg FROM scores";
// prepare the statement
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
// bind parameters and execute the query
$query->execute(array(':msg_a' => $msg_a, ':msg_b' => $msg_b));
// fetch the resultset
$rows = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```